# How to construct a triangle from...?

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

- Two medians and one height (nothing is for the same side!);
- Outer circle radius, one side and another side's height?

Using Compass-and-straightedge construction.

Comment: First of all, you know where the medians intersect by 2:1 ratio

Comment: ...yes :) I also have an idea of extending the triangle to a parallelogram... but nothing else after that

Comment: I recommend starting with the altitude. Draw the line of given length and draw a line perpendicular to one of its end points.

Comment: ...alright, done now what? :D

Comment: It was only a recommendation, I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Oh... okay :// Well, then I think I'll just have to wait for other clever people :D

Comment: Which of the two medians are given? The medians of the other 2 sides?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38821/discussion-between-n-s-john-and-forcemagic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Two medians and one height 1

[image: Two medians and one height 1]

Given: $AE$, $BD$, $AF$.

1. Draw $AF$.
2. Construct perpendicular in $F$.
3. Draw circle around $A$ with radius $AE$.
4. Intersect 2. and 3. to obtain $E$.
5. Construct $G$ on $AE$ such that $AG:GE=2:1$.
6. Construct circle around $G$ with radius $\frac23\cdot BD$.
7. Intersect 2. and 6. to obtain $B$.
8. Measure distance $BD$ along $BG$ to find $D$.
9. Intersect $AD$ with 2. to find $C$.

---

### Two medians and one height 2

[image: Two medians and one height 2]

Given: $AE$, $BD$, $CF$.

1. Draw $BD$.
2. Construct $K$ as midpoint on $BD$.
3. Construct circle around $K$ through $B$ (and $D$).
4. Construct circle around $D$ with radius $\frac12\cdot CF$.
5. Intersect 3. and 4. to obtain $H$.
6. Construct $G$ on $BD$ such that $BG:GD=2:1$.
7. Construct circle around $G$ with radius $\frac23\cdot AE$.
8. Intersect 7. with $BH$ to obtain $A$.
9. Reflect $A$ in $D$ to obtain $C$.

---

### Outer circle radius, one side and another side's height

[image: Outer circle radius, one side and another side's height]

Given: Circumcircle radius, $AB$ and $AD$.

1. Draw circumcircle.
2. Construct side $AB$ as a segment of that circle.
3. Construct midpoint $E$ of $AB$.
4. Draw circle with center $E$ through $A$ (and $B$).
5. Draw circle around $A$ with radius $AD$.
6. Intersect 4. and 5. to get $D$.
7. Intersect $BD$ with circumcircle to get $C$.

Comment: Awesome answer, great explanation! Saved me around a day of looking up on the internet :)

Comment: Also, one more thing: I know I was a little vague in the question but the 2 medians and the height are all for different sides. Already edited btw.

Comment: @ForceMagic: Added that case as well.

Comment: Thanks, now I can accept it :)